# Option on Futures vs. Stocks

Tags: black-scholes, equities, futures

The Black-Scholes call on a Futures is valued as:
$$
C_t=e^{-r(T-t)}[F_tN(d_1)-KN(d_2)]
$$
It holds: $F_t=S_te^{r(T-t)}$.

If I plug this back in, I get the Black-Scholes call on a stock:

$$
C_t=S_tN(d_1)-e^{-r(T-t)}KN(d_2)
$$
Does this mean that the option on a futures has the same value as the option on a stock in theory?

Comment: Yes, it is the same formula, but with a change of variables. It was Fischer Black in 1976 who first pointed out the relationship, and derived the first formula from the second.